# How can I decimal-align tick labels at the left?

Tags: plotting

I use the `CustomTicks` package, because the built-in tick labeling leaves a lot to be desired.  Even just putting the tick marks on the right instead of the left is a real pain without  `CustomTicks`, from what I remember. I think this would be an issue even without this package, though.

Here is what I type in:

```
<< "CustomTicks`"
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}, 
  Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
  FrameTicks -> {Automatic, StripTickLabels[LinTicks], Automatic, LinTicks},
  BaseStyle -> 18]
```

and here is what I get:

[image]

I think the tick marks on the right look awful. They would be better if aligned on the decimal rather than on the left.  But how do I fix this?  My current workaround is to make another version of the plot with tick labels on the left, which usually are aligned properly because they align to the right.  Then I cut the labels from that image and paste them onto the image I want.

Any other solution?

Comment: A simple, but crude way would be to prepend a transparent `-` to the positive ticks...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way is to build your own ticks and format the numerical values for the ticks yourself.
Here is a quick hack, just for illustration. I left the left side ticks as Automatic, to compare, and adjusted the right side and the lower side ticks as you wanted. You can play with this and adjust as needed.

[image]

```
padIt1[v_, f_List] := AccountingForm[Chop[v],
   f, NumberSigns -> {"-", "+"}, NumberPadding -> {"0", "0"},SignPadding -> True];
padIt2[v_, f_Integer] := AccountingForm[Round[v],
   f, NumberSigns -> {"", ""}, NumberPadding -> {"0", "0"}, SignPadding -> True];

fticks1[min_, max_] := 
  Table[If[Mod[i, 0.5] == 0, {i, padIt1[i, {3, 2}], {.03, 0.0}, 
     Red}, {i, Null, {0.01, 0.0}}], {i, Ceiling[min], Floor[max], .1}];

fticks2[min_, max_] := 
  Table[If[Mod[i, 1] == 0, {i, padIt2[i, 1], {.03, 0.0}, Red}, {i, 
     Null, {0.01, 0.0}}], {i, Ceiling[min], Floor[max], .2}];

Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, fticks1}, {fticks2, Automatic}}, BaseStyle -> 18]
```

This diagram explains the arguments in the above tick functions

[image]

Comment: Would `NumberSigns -> {"-", " "}` be even closer to what the OP wanted?

Answer (score 7):

**Update 2:** a function to customize frame ticks:

```
 ClearAll[ticksF];
ticksF[majorminor_List: {5, 5}, mjrtcklngth_: {.01, 0.}, exmpl_: "-.500", 
 nmbrfrm_: {3, 2}][min_, max_] := Module[{majordivs, minordivs},
 {majordivs, minordivs} = Switch[Head[majorminor[[1]]],
 List, majorminor, 
 _, FindDivisions[{min, max}, majorminor]];
 Join[{#, "", mjrtcklngth/2.} & /@ DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[minordivs]],
 {#, Overlay[{Invisible[exmpl],
    Switch[Sign[nmbrfrm[[2]]],
     0, IntegerPart[N@#],
     -1, "",
     _, NumberForm[N@#, nmbrfrm]]},
   Alignment -> Right], mjrtcklngth} & /@ majordivs]]
```

Usage examples:

```
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
 BaseStyle -> 18, ImageSize -> 500,
 FrameTicks -> {
 {ticksF[{Range[-1, 1, .2], Range[-1, 1, .05]}, {0.02,  0.}, "", {0, -1}],
 ticksF[]},
 {ticksF[{7, 5}, {0.01, 0.}, "5", {3, 0}],
 ticksF[{7, 1}, {0.01, 0.}, "500", {3, 2}]}}]
```

[image]

```
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]},
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False, BaseStyle -> 18, ImageSize -> 500,
 FrameTicks -> {
 {ticksF[{Range[-1, 1, .2], Range[-1, 1, .05]}, {0.02, 0.}, "", {0, -1}],
 ticksF[{Range[-1, 1, .2], Range[-1, 1, .1]}]},
 {ticksF[{7, 5}, {0.01, 0.}, "5", {3, 0}],
  ticksF[{7, 1}, {0.01, 0.}, "500", {3, 2}]}},
 FrameTicksStyle -> {Directive[Green, Thick, FontWeight -> Bold, FontColor -> Purple],
   Directive[Red, Thickness[Large]], Automatic, 
   Directive[Brown, Bold]}]
```

[image]

---

```
 rightTicks = {#, Pane[NumberForm[N@#, {3, 2}], 45, Alignment -> Right]} & /@ 
  Range[-1, 1, 2/8];
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, BaseStyle -> 18,
 ImageSize -> 500, FrameTicks -> {{None, rightTicks}, {Automatic, None}}]
```

[image]

or, replace `rightTicks` by `rightTicks2`, where

```
rightTicks2 = {#,   Framed[NumberForm[N@#, {3, 2}], Alignment -> Right, 
  ImageSize -> 50, FrameMargins -> 0, FrameStyle -> None]} & /@ Range[-1, 1, 2/8];
```

In both cases, one needs to manually adjust the image size of the container.

**Update:** another trick using `Overlay` and `Invisible`:

```
 rightTicks3 = {#, Overlay[{Invisible["-0.75"], NumberForm[N@#, {3, 2}]}, 
 Alignment -> Right]} & /@ Range[-1, 1, 2/8]
```

Answer (score 4):

Just a quick hack (without using CustomTicks)

```
Show[#, BaseStyle -> 14, FrameTicks -> (FrameTicks /. AbsoluteOptions[#, FrameTicks] /. 
{x_, y_, w_, z_}:> {x, z, w, y /. ({a_, b_, c_, d_} /; b >= 0 :> {a, "+"<>ToString@b, c, d})})]&@ 
     Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Great quick workaround, but it brings up the one of the big headaches I encountered trying to make my own tick marks. Now they do align on the decimal, but some have one digit, some two, and some three.  Is one of the main reasons I use CustomTicks.

Comment: @Jimbo But you can fix it with NumberForm if you like. `Show[#, BaseStyle -> 14,
   FrameTicks -> (FrameTicks /. AbsoluteOptions[#, FrameTicks] /.
      {x_, y_, w_, z_} :> {x, z, w, 
        y /. ({a_, b_, c_, d_} /; b != "" :> {a, 
            ToString@
             NumberForm[ToExpression@b, {5, 2}, 
              NumberSigns -> {"+", "-"}, NumberPadding -> {"", "0"}], 
            c, d})})] &@
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all the answers given, especially those from Nasser and kguler.  It turns out there is an easy way to do this using the LinTicks function.  I love using the CustomTicks package, where they've already done a lot of the work for me.

```
<< "CustomTicks`"
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}, 
  Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
  FrameTicks -> {Automatic, StripTickLabels[LinTicks], Automatic, 
    LinTicks[-1, 1, .5, 5, TickLabelFunction -> (If[#1 >= 0.0, "+" <> #2, #2] &)]},
  BaseStyle -> 18]
```

gives this result:

[image]